# UpdateProgress and trigger section not working in Update panel while implement file upload control asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I am trying to upload image files with asp.net file upload control inside an update panel. I want to process UpdateProgress to show a progress bar image indicating a progress as well along with the file upload.

**Case 1:** When I remove the trigger section and use UpdateProgress section, the progress procedure is working fine but the file upload  control fails to upload my files. [*The page doesnot reload*]

**Case 2:** When I use trigger section and remove UpdateProgress section, the file gets uploaded but the page gets reloaded.

**Expected: What I really want is a fine file upload process that includes UpdateProgress to show progress image and strictly with no page loads.**

**What I have been to is:**

**.aspx section**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>


<asp:UpdateProgress ID="loading" runat="server">

<ProgressTemplate>

<asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="loadingGeneral" ImageUrl="../Images/loading(1).gif" AlternateText="Processing" runat="server" />

</ProgressTemplate>

  </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadForAlbum" multiple="true" CssClass="buttonclass"  runat="server"  ToolTip="Click to browse image." />
    <asp:Button ID="btn_uploadAlbum" runat="server" class="buttonclass" OnClick="btnUploadAlbum_Click" Text="Upload Slider" />

    </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
             <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_uploadAlbum" />
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**.aspx.cs section**

File upload code section is fine and I have used following to implement progress bar.

```
   protected void btnUploadAlbum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            do something.........
}
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a very complex problem that has been solved by numerous third-party tools.  My tool of choice for async uploads is PlUpload: http://plupload.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some interesting facts to know about `FileUpload` control.

1.) file upload control doesn't work with asynchronous postback. It always needs a postback to work properly. This is the reason why you see full page postbacks.

2.) AsyncPostbackTrigger  will not help here to prevent postback.

[**`MSDN`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) says clearly that:

```
The FileUpload control is designed to be used only in postback scenarios 
and not in asynchronous postback scenarios during partial-page rendering.
When you use a FileUpload control inside an UpdatePanel control, the file must
be uploaded by using a control that is a PostBackTrigger object for the panel
```

This makes to infer our third point:

3.) We need to use `PostBackTrigger` to make the `FileUpload` control work with `UpdatePanel`, which is then going to have a full page postback.

***Your Question***:

```
What I really want is a fine file upload process that includes UpdateProgress 
to show progress image and strictly with no page loads
```

One of the good answer to this is to use the `AsyncFileUpload` control.
Features of this control:

- It works within the Update Panel
- You can show the loading image while file uploading is in progress, using `ThrobberID` property.
- It uploads the file without any postback
- It provides Client Side and Server side events
- There are different coloring options for showing file upload. As for example, it shows green color if upload is successful: Use the `CompleteBackColor` property, otherwise it shows red if there is unsuccessful upload, using `ErrorBackColor` property.

On your `.aspx` page, place a script manager and register the Ajax control toolkit DLL.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxasyncFU" %>
```

Now place the `AsyncFileUpload` control:

```
<ajaxasyncFU:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" 
OnClientUploadError="uploadError" OnClientUploadStarted="StartUpload" 
OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete" 
CompleteBackColor="Lime" UploaderStyle="Modern" 
ErrorBackColor="Red" ThrobberID="Throbber" 
onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" 
UploadingBackColor="#66CCFF" />
```

There are 3 client events you can use: `OnClientUploadError`, `OnClientUploadStarted`, and `OnClientUploadComplete`

And one Server side event: `onuploadedcomplete`, which is called in asynchronous manner thus avoiding full page postback.
In this server event usually we save the file:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete
    (object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{      
  if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
  {
    string strPath = MapPath("~/MyImages/") + Path.GetFileName(e.filename);
    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(strPath);
  }
}
```

Check these 2 links: [**`Link1`**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42865/AsyncFileUpload-Control-New-Control-in-Ajax-Contro) , [**`Link2`**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ASP.Net-AJAX-Control-Toolkits-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx) for further reading.